# What's the difference between token tracker and address page in Etherscan?

Tags: tokens, etherscan, dai

As an example, let's use DAI.

DAI has these pages in Etherscan:

- https://etherscan.io/token/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f
- https://etherscan.io/address/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f

It seems like the first one will track all the transactions but what about the second page? I'm confused in trying to differentiate between those two.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second bullet shows the token (in this case, DAI) as an Ethereum address. Etherscan shows a page with the same properties for all Ethereum addresses, such as "Internal Txns", "Erc20 Token Txns", "Erc721 Token Txns", etc. This type of address page will display the same properties for **any** address, whether it is an EOA, a contract, a token, or something else.

Your first bullet shows Etherscan's token page. Etherscan shows additional, token-specific properties, such as "Transfers", "Holders", "Info", etc. for tokens. This type of token page **only** applies to tokens and is used to provide additional insights about tokens that do not apply to all addresses.

Comment: I guess it's just a different view provided for Etherscan to help viewers in getting the right information