# Why huge difference between number of address transfers and token transactions on etherscan?

Tags: tokens, etherscan, address.transfer

I am trying to use the etherscan API to get the list the most traded tokens in a day.I came accross this endpoint, but as shown above, it does not contain all the token transactions (as shown in the token page).

```
https://api.etherscan.io//api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0xf0f9D895aCa5c8678f706FB8216fa22957685A13&startblock=0&endblock=999999999&page=1&offset=10000&sort=desc&apikey=xxx
```

I don't understand why difference in number of transaction between these two lists of transactions on etherscan:

- https://etherscan.io/token/0xf0f9d895aca5c8678f706fb8216fa22957685a13  . transactions : 133,394
- https://etherscan.io/address/0xf0f9d895aca5c8678f706fb8216fa22957685a13 . transactions : 15,503

The contract is the same but the number of transaction is really different. I have reviewed other questions but it does not speak about the number of transaction [What's the difference between token tracker and address page in Etherscan?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89776/whats-the-difference-between-token-tracker-and-address-page-in-etherscan)

Any observation or suggestion would be most helpful !

Comment: internal transaction are not count as transaction in that page

Comment: what page , addresses transfer ? still don't understand the huge discrepancy. Token transaction page has almost 10x more transaction

Comment: When a smart contract is used call a method in your token contract then it is count as "internal" transaction and it is not shown as a normal transaction. For example When you swap token on uniswap then the contract of uniswap is calling your token contract and you are not interacting directly with your contract. therefore there is a internal tx but not a normal tx

Comment: ok it's clear now. Got it